# In Xcode, create framework as target in same project as app vs separate project for framework

Tags: xcode, ios-frameworks, xcode14, xcode15, xcode-target

### Main question

Here is my scenario: I have app *A* in Xcode project *X*. I will create framework *F* to use in app *A*. I could create framework *F* inside project *X* as another target. I could also create a new project *Y* to hold framework *F*.

**What are the differences (capabilities, features) between those 2 choices?**

The only thing I can think of is that separate Xcode projects make sharing of the framework source code easier. Everything else that I can think of is minor. The flexibility of schemes and targets in a single project eliminates most other differences that I can think of.

Examples of minor differences if choosing separate project:

- a shorter list of targets
- target does not inherit build settings from app project
- framework will show up as blue icon in Project Navigator instead of gray folder icon

### Meta points

No one seems to have written about this exact topic. Hence, why I am posting this question.

#### Duplicate question?

I wish this question was a duplicate but all other related questions that I have surveyed are about:

- what frameworks are and how to create them
- what targets are and how to create them
- what Xcode workspaces and projects are and how to use them
- how to extract app code into a separate framework

I am not asking any of these things.

#### Reason for xcode14 tag

So many questions and articles and docs are for ancient version of Xcode (like 4) and with the last two version of Xcode (14 & 15), the build system has been updated significantly. Answers to my question could be quite different for older versions of Xcode.